# r - bar chart with color corresponding to the actual level of the data

Tags: r, bar-chart

Is it possible to produce a bar chart and color the bar according to the level of each bar, just like the example below?
[image: Color bar chart]

Comment: @Selina: You should ask for more :)

Answer (score 2):

Yup:

```
example.data <- data.frame(time=1:100, value=rnorm(100))
ggplot(example.data) + geom_bar(aes(x=time, y=value, fill=value), stat='identity')
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful. Based on this, this my final code:

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful. Based on this, this is my final code:
    example.data <- data.frame(time=1:100, value=rnorm(100))
    ggplot(example.data) + geom_bar(aes(x=time, y=value, fill=value), stat='identity') + scale_fill_gradient2(low="deepskyblue3", mid='white', high='red', midpoint=0)

So I can have blue for negative values and red for postive values.

Comment: Glad it helped - feel free to hit the little check mark next to my answer :)